# View Cloud Firestore query/command history

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am coding a Flutter app and using Cloud Firestore as DB. I am still in the development phase, but if I go to quota it looks like I have some serious traffic on API calls (5000+ per day) and up to 2000 fetched objects.

These numbers look oddly high to me, and I have few hypothesis, but I don't have any tool to investigate: **is there a way to browse the history of the issued calls/commands to Cloud Firestore?** It would be nice to have the `auth.uid` of the call issuer and some other details (time, location, etc.).

---

Notice: I know I could implement something like that myself, using a Firebase Function, but I'd rather rely on provider-side infos and at this moment such overhead would be killing my efforts for days.

Comment: Note that you can also simply log the calls directly from the client to a central location. That takes much less time to set up than replacing the entire API with Cloud Functions, and may already uncover where the unexpected calls are coming from.

Comment: It's not useful to log from client, since I can't relate calls and quota changes, and I don't mean to change APIs but to have Cloud Functions triggered by DB events directly. Anyhow thanks for the effort ;)

Answer (score 3):

*Firebase employee here*

There is no way to get a report of the queries that were made to Firestore.  You'll have to find a way to log those on your own.

Comment: All feature requests can go here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I've created a feature request for this as well. Having costs as a black box makes me profoundly uncomfortable.